# Reading variable from Firebase childs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I have many Telegram Keyboards in my Firebase**, and I Want to Get Childs of specific keyboard that the user clicks on,
And `msg.text` is Variable of my Keyboards

```
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/Keyboard1/childs');  //keyboard 1
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/Keyboard2/childs');  //keyboard 2
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/Keyboard3/childs');  //keyboard 3
```

How to add `Keyboard[n]`, I mean `msg.text` in my `ref`?
If my input `msg.text` was = `Keyboard1` I get `Keyboard1` Childs and ...

**It did not work**

```
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/msg.text/childs');
```

**Notice** When my Project was local with local json, I used below Code for this and Works Fine:
`locale.keyboards[msg.text].childs`

Comment: did you try to use db.ref('Keyboards/' + msg.text + '/childs');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
db.ref('Keyboards/' + msg.text + '/childs');
```